ffmpeg - Trouble using if statement with overlay
I would like to apply a .png on two frames of my input video but
I'm having trouble using an if statement to determine the location of the overlay.
Expected: 
Frame n°7 -> Frame n°7 + overlay.png with pos(300,700) 
Frame n°12 -> Frame n°12 + overlay.png with pos(0,0) 
Frame n°?? -> Frame n°??
Here is the ffmpeg command found on this post with similar use-cases: How to have an overlay move to specific points at specific frames using ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(eq(n,7),300,0)':y='if(eq(n,7),700,0)':enable='eq(n,7)+eq(n,12)'[out]" -map [out] output.mkv

But in my case, the if condition x='if(eq(n,7),300,0)' and y='if(eq(n,7),700,0)' always return false and I do not understand why this is happening.
Thanks!

...:enable='eq(n,6... in x y → n starts from 1? in enable → n starts from 0?

@БаярГончикжапов
It works! Thank you very much!
